# Rational Functional Tester dropdownlist select

Tags: java, html, rft

I'm working on automation project, and I'm trying to select a html dropdown list and the item in the list with JAVA-code (not javascript). Apparently the best way to this is the GuiSubitemTestObject but on constructing the method i can't find any examples. Does anyone have an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SelectGuiSubitemTestObject object_for_select = ((SelectGuiSubitemTestObject) to[0]);
      try {
//      ITestDataList dataList = (ITestDataList)object_for_select.getTestData("list");
//      ITestDataElementList elementList = (ITestDataElementList)dataList.getElements();
//          for(int i = 0; i<elementList.getLength(); i++) {
//        This statement prints the Items of the Listbox or combo box.
//        System.out.println("Item Index  "+i+" "+elementList.getElement(i).getElement().toString());
//      }
    object_for_select.select(what_to_set);
  }
```